# How can I get the description of an image file with PHP?

Tags: php, file, filesystems

How can I get the description of a file with PHP? I've done some reasearch and haven't found any specific function or anything so what do you think?

Comment: Where is this description? Do you mean attached to the file, or in HTML after the `IMG` tag, or something else?

Comment: @Pete, images have metadata all the time in the form of exif tags.  If you can't tell us what you want, we can't help you.

Comment: jesus bro keep ur pants on im trying to exaplin. Images have built-in descriptions right? Thats what I'm looking for to save a description to the image. I asked this very clearly. Now if that is not realistic than please tell me about these meta tags in to the form of a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some image format support metadata. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php for reading Exif metadata. It sounds like you're interested in the `COMPUTED.UserComment` property.